# Excel VBA Chart counting and formatting

Tags: excel, vba, charts, counting

I'd like to create a macro that counts the number of charts within a given range, then performs certain actions depending on the number counted. I know `activesheet.chartobjects.count` would count across the whole sheet, how would I modify to count within a range?

Here's the skeleton of my code.

```
Sub chrt_chck()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:F10")
    x = ActiveSheet.rng.ChartObjects.Count
    
    If x > 1 Then
    'select and delete all charts in range
    End If
    
    If x = 1 Then
    'select that chart and update format
    Else
    'create chart and set format
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub chrt_chck()
    Dim rng As Range, chO As ChartObject, x As Long, arrChO() As ChartObject, k As Long, El
    
    Set rng = Range("B2:D15") ' Range("A1:F10")
    ReDim arrChO(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.count - 1)
    For Each chO In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        If Not Intersect(chO.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
            x = x + 1
            Set arrChO(k) = chO: k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    If x > 1 Then
    'select and delete all charts in range
        For Each El In arrChO
            Debug.Print El.name
            El.Delete
        Next
    End If
    
    If x = 1 Then
    'select that chart and update format
         With arrChO(0)
            .Select
            Debug.Print .name
            'do wahtever needed with the chart...
         End With
    Else
    'create chart and set format
    End If
End Sub
```

It counts all chart objects having their Top Left corner inside the `rng` Range.

Comment: Why did you define both x and k? k seems unnecessary to me. Regardless the code is effective.

Comment: @Elis: `arrChO` is a zero based array and `x` must count the charts... K is initially 0. I could use `X - 1` here, but I got used to have a separate variable for that. Sometimes, there are conditional iterations where it is good to use something easy to be checked at the end, if necessary, without being confused by the iterated variable. I can say, it is a matter of habit... A good habit, I would (still) dare to believe... :) I could also declare the array `1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.count`, also. But my experience made me use the solution I am using.

Comment: Minor fix: When the sheet includes no charts the `arrChO(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.count - 1)` evaluates as `arrChO(-1)` and spits out an error, so I've indented the `Redim` and `for` loop in an IF Statment, that depends on the value of `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.count`.

Comment: Check before if count >0... now I am driving.